# Accessing form data from POST in JPA embedded table

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Im running a Spring MVC application using JPA for persistence. I have a form which has an update button. When this button is clicked its supposed to update a users record in the database. The User table has an embedded table Address in it. I am able to access all the fields in the User table but not the embedded table. Here is my Request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userid}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String Update(@ModelAttribute("user")User user,@PathVariable("userid") String userid,Model model){
```

Here is my User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="phone_user", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userid")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="phoneid")})
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }
    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }
```

}
Note the @Embedded tag of Address field. 
Here is my Address.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zip; 
    @Column(name="street")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    @Column(name="city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Column(name="state")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    @Column(name="zip")
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }


}
```

Here is my JSP which sends the form data

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>



<form method="POST" action="/cmpe275/user/${userid}">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="userid" value="${id}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="firstname" value="${firstname}"/></td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="lastname" value="${lastname}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><tr><tr><tr>
    <td>Street</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="street" value="${street}"/></td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="city" value="${city}"/></td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="state" value="${state}"/></td>
    <td>Zip</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="zip" value="${zip}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><tr><tr><tr>
    <td><input type="submit" onclick="updateUser();" name="Update" value="Update"/></td>

    <td><input type="button" name="Delete" value="Delete"/></td>



</table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
function updateUser(){
    console.log("hi");
}

</script>
</html>
```

I am unable to access the address fields using the getter/setters.
For example - In my handler mapping - To get the first name of the updated profile I can access it using :

```
user.getFirstName()
```

But If i want to access the updated Address I do a

```
user.getAddress.getCity()
```

I get a null value.
Any idea why?

Comment: can you post some client side code and what the request looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this

```
<td><input type="text"  name="street" value="${street}"/></td>
<td>City</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="city" value="${city}"/></td>
<td>State</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="state" value="${state}"/></td>
<td>Zip</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="zip" value="${zip}"/></td>
```

should be

```
<td><input type="text"  name="address.street" value="${address.street}"/></td>
<td>City</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="address.city" value="${address.city}"/></td>
<td>State</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="address.state" value="${address.state}"/></td>
<td>Zip</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="address.zip" value="${address.zip}"/></td>
```

A spring controller is expecting the `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` to be structured like the POJO.  So if you where not using a form and sending this data vs some js it would look something like

```
{ 
  'firstname':'peter',
  'lastname': 'griffen',
  'address': {
      'street':'31 Spooner Street'        
   }
}
```

What you had was the object completely flat.  Which might work if you add the correct setters in the User class.

Comment: This works. Can you please elaborate and tell me what was the problem?